# UWP Relativepanel bound to UiElement doesn't work like RelativePanel with propertie = UiElement

Tags: xaml, responsive-design, visual-studio-2015

We are developing a Windows10 Universal App (UWP). We have huge issues related to how RelativePanel behave depending of syntax and pc.
We have dynamic data response from a web service and we have to display a dynamic structure of UI controls to render the GUI.
We are trying to use RelativePanels with child elements composed of ItemsControls rendering different type of sub data (Addresses, Phones, etc..).
The ItemTemplate of each ItemsControl' item is a Template composed of a RelativePanel.

Now, the weird stuff happened differently between design and runtime.
At design time, when we want to set Target UIElement of the RelativePanel, we can use the following syntax:

1. Ex: `RelativePanel.Below="EntryMobileNumbers"` or
2. Ex: `RelativePanel.Below="{Binding ElementName=EntryMobileNumbers}" />`

They are supposed to both work but they don't.
For some RelativePanels’ child elements, if we use the first syntax, the xaml designer bugs and display weird error message
about “value must be of type UIElement”.

[image]

Looked on forums for this type of Xaml error and it seems for some developers it’s better to use the second syntax with the Binding.
The good side of it is with that the design is not displaying the squigglys and the error BUT the pb is at Run-time;
the result is wrong and some elements are overlapping.

With syntax 2

[image]

With syntax 1

[image]

We have also different issues between dev pc’s. With the VS2015 Enterprise installed on all pc’s,
some are displaying squigglys or crash the Xaml Designer with Syntax 1 and some are not.
We also tried to update VS2015 with yesterday’s RC1. It fixed the issues on one of the Pc and not on the others.

PS. All samples out there are very simple. I would very happy to see a "real life" application.
Like e.g. Money from the store to see how layout are managed

Comment: Yep, same here. And Update 1 didn't do anything to fix it. :-(

Comment: I also experienced that issue, my hack is to add an element, let's say a button, with AlignRightWithPanel=True and AlignTopWithPanel=True on the main RelativePanel. Then I just set the visibility of that element to collapse since I don't really need it. It's kind of a hack that's why I don't want to post it to the answers. But it works for me. I feel like the controls are all overlapping to the left side because there's nothing stretching the container to the right. I may be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

RelativePanel.Above="{Binding ElementName=SubTitleDesktop}"

instead of

RelativePanel.Above="SubTitleDesktop"

and it will helps you get rid off errors